# Android facebook birthday error

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to use the login button for facebook and I am able to successfully login. I have set the permissions as -

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
            "public_profile","email","user_birthday"));
```

But the problem is that some people keep their birthday as private. And in such cases when I am trying to access the birthday, the app is going to the catch block -

```
try {
                        user = new User();
                        user.facebookID = object.getString("id").toString();
                        user.email = object.getString("email").toString();
                        user.name = object.getString("name").toString();
                        user.gender = object.getString("gender").toString();
                        PrefUtils.setCurrentUser(user, LoginActivity.this);
                        user.birthday = object.getString("birthday").toString();

                        Log.d("LoginActivity","in executeGraphRequest user.birthday = "+user.birthday);

                        //PrefUtils.setCurrentUser(user, LoginActivity.this);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I can understand why it is going to the catch block. But I want to know how we can know in advance, before querying, that the information we are querying is private. This can apply not just to birthday but other fields too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is the error in catch block

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
if(object.has("birthday"))
    user.birthday = object.getString("birthday").toString();
```